# FC try to start my Android AccessibilityService

Tags: java, android, api, service

I am using Jelly Bean v16 API, follow the Guide here: [Developing an Accessibility Service](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html)

I haven't start to add anything, just a blank service, but it crash instantly after I try to start the service.

here is the code, which part I did wrong?

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.firstapp.service"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

`MyAccessibilityService.java`:

```
package com.example.android.apis.accessibility;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

}
```

this is the error message of LogCat (and there are more).

```
07-17 18:38:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 18:38:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.firstapp.service.MyAccessibilityService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.firstapp.service.MyAccessibilityService
07-17 18:38:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2347)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest is declaring the service to live within the Java package `com.firstapp.service`, whereas the actual class is implemented in the `com.example.android.apis.accessibility` package.

Change the package name in the `MyAccessibilityService.java` file to: `com.firstapp.service`